# ST_PointN equivalent in SDO_GEOMETRY?

Tags: sql, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms, vertices, sdo-geometry

In SDE.ST_GEOMETRY, we have a function called ST_PointN:

> [ST_PointN](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/using-sql-with-gdbs/st-pointn.htm) takes an ST_LineString and an integer index and returns a
> point that is the nth vertex in the ST_LineString's path.
>
> ```
> sde.st_pointn (line1 sde.st_linestring, index integer)
> ```
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> SELECT gid, sde.st_astext (sde.st_pointn (ln1, 2)) The_2ndvertex
>  FROM POINTN_TEST;
>
> GID   The_2ndvertex
> ----  -----------------------------
> 1     POINT (23.73 21.92)
> 2     POINT ZM (23.73 21.92 6.5 7.1)
> ```

Question:

Does Oracle's native datatype SDO_GEOMETRY have an equivalent function?

Related:

- [Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570611/why-does-shape-sdo-ordinates1-work-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-sql)
- [Get X & Y coordinates from GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT()](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499536/get-x-y-coordinates-from-geom-segment-start-pt)
- [Why does GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT() return SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY, not an SDO_POINT?](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16838284)
- [Idea: Function to get a 2D line's startpoint (as SDO_POINT)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499540/idea-function-to-get-a-2d-lines-startpoint-as-sdo-point)
- [Support extracting collection elements by index in SQL](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499553/support-extracting-collection-elements-by-index-in-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to my previous "do-it-yourself" answer, there is actually a function that does this ... Only it’s called differently. And it’s not documented ...

The function is: **SDO_UTIL.GET_COORDINATE(geometry, point_number)**

Where **point_number** is the number of the point to return (1 is the first point, -1 means: return the last point). The function works with all geometry dimensions: 2D, 3D, or LRS.

For example:

```
with lines as (
  select SDO_GEOMETRY(
    2002, 4326, NULL, 
    SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1), 
    SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(
      -85.293434, 35.018185, 
      -85.295677, 35.01944, 
      -85.297104, 35.02063, 
      -85.298569, 35.022507,
      -85.300278, 35.02351, 
      -85.303017, 35.025379, 
      -85.304947, 35.02655, 
      -85.306267, 35.027103, 
      -85.306419, 35.027397, 
      -85.307411, 35.02795
    )
  ) as geom
  from dual
)
select 
  sdo_util.get_coordinate (geom, 1) as first_point,
  sdo_util.get_coordinate (geom, -1) as last_point,
  sdo_util.get_coordinate (geom, 5) as point#5
from lines;
```

which returns the following:

```
FIRST_POINT                                                                       LAST_POINT                                                                       POINT#5
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-85.293434, 35.018185, NULL), NULL, NULL) SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-85.307411, 35.02795, NULL), NULL, NULL) SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, 4326, SDO_POINT_TYPE(-85.300278, 35.02351, NULL), NULL, NULL)
 
1 row selected.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do below to get vertex at an index from a linestring in Oracle SDO_GEOMETRY

```
SELECT 
    l.lid, 
    t.X, 
    t.Y, 
    t.id
FROM 
    tblLines l,
    TABLE(SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(l.geometry)) t 
where 
    t.id= <<Index of the vertex>>
ORDER BY 
    l.lId, 
    t.id;
```

Comment: You just need to pass the index number instead of <>. For example, if you need 2nd vertex of the geometry, then you need to pass t.id=2

Comment: I think I get it now. It's kind of like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO4y5.png ... Source: [Cross join on a numbers table to get line vertices](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154995/cross-join-on-a-numbers-table-to-get-line-vertices-is-there-a-better-way)

Comment: What ever I shared should give correct result based on your original question. Please let me know if you faced any issue with it. May be you can write a procedure or function if you want to reuse it at many places or in loop.

Comment: FYI - It turns out the `Table()` keyword is no longer necessary in queries like that. We can cross join directly to the `GetVertices()` function to get the vertices as rows. [Cross-joining with a table object propagates rows (without needing Table() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590279/cross-joining-with-a-table-object-propagates-rows-without-needing-table-funct).

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent out of the box. But implementing such a function is easy with a bit of PL/SQL:

```
create or replace function st_pointn (g sdo_geometry, n number)
return sdo_geometry
as
begin
  return (
    sdo_geometry (
      2001,
      g.sdo_srid,
      sdo_point_type (
        g.sdo_ordinates((n-1) * 2 + 1),
        g.sdo_ordinates((n-1) * 2 + 2),
        null
      ),
      null,
      null
    )
  );
end;
/
```

This function needs improving: make it more generic for the dimensionality of the input, check the validity of the point number ... That is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Here's another possible option for a custom function: `return shape.sdo_ordinates(1);`. Related: [Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570611/why-does-shape-sdo-ordinates1-work-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-sql).