# Extract SDO_GEOMETRY line elements using index position / dot notation

Tags: geojson, sql, coordinates, oracle-spatial, oracle-dbms

SDO_GEOMETRY; Oracle 18c:

Is there a way to extract elements from an SDO_GEOMETRY line using an index position / dot-notation in a SQL query?

For example, extract the **X coordinate of the second vertex** using this fake syntax: `shape.coordinates[1][0]`.

```
--get the X coordinate of the second vertex: 30
with data as (select sdo_geometry('linestring(10 20, 30 40, 50 60)') as shape from dual)

select 
    (shape).coordinates[1][0] as x  --Zero-based numbering. [1] would be the second vertex. [0] would be the first ordinate: X.
from 
    data
```

```
Error:

ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 24
```

It's not surprising that fake syntax failed. But I *am* curious if there's a way to do this kind of thing using *proper* Oracle SQL syntax.

---

I'm aware that there are other ways to get coordinates, such as:

- A cross join and the [GetVertices()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-9CF1E8A9-EBCB-4938-BBB6-C2AAFE4897A7) function.
- Or, `sdo_util.get_coordinate(shape,2).sdo_point.x`: [ST_PointN equivalent in SDO_GEOMETRY?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/425057/62572)
- Or, get a specific ordinate using a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570611/why-does-shape-sdo-ordinates1-work-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-sql): `return shape.sdo_ordinates(1);`.
- Or, if we specifically wanted the startpoint or endpoint, use:  [`sdo_lrs.geom_segment_start_pt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_LRS-reference.html#GUID-0BAFDBEF-B83C-49B8-97EC-6842EA14A1C4) or [`sdo_lrs.geom_segment_end_pt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/SDO_LRS-reference.html#GUID-F5518D1F-F90D-400B-AE1C-3C2BA7A611EC).
- Or, use [`cross join lateral`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72583361/5576771).
- Or, [get ordinates as rows in a query.](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499613/get-ordinates-as-rows-in-query-sdo-geometry)
- Some of those options would be used in conjunction with getting the [`(shape).sdo_point.x`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/spatl/spatial-datatypes-metadata.html#GUID-04642757-36CC-4ACE-BA1F-B1AAF7D83731) attribute, etc.

I'm just trying to learn what *all* the options are. And I'm wondering if there's a way to do it using index positions / dot-notation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the answer is "sort of", using JSON and GeoJSON:

```
--get the X coordinate of the second vertex: 30
with data as (select sdo_geometry('linestring(10 20, 30 40, 50 60)') as shape from dual)

select 
    json_value((shape).Get_GeoJson(),'$.coordinates[1][0]' returning number) as x  --Zero-based numbering. [1] is the second vertex. [0] is the first ordinate: X.
from 
    data


Result: 

         X
----------
        30
```

Source: [Idea: Add a SDO_ORDINATES member function (for extracting collection elements by index)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16840191/#Comment_16840191)

Related: [Why does SHAPE.SDO_ORDINATES(1) work in PL/SQL, but not in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72570611/why-does-shape-sdo-ordinates1-work-in-pl-sql-but-not-in-sql)

---

With that said, using JSON in queries seems like an unappealing practice to me. It could quickly become unmanageable, since it's so different from SQL.

For example:

I think it would be confusing to have to deal with two different numbering systems in the same query:

- SQL and PL/SQL: one-based numbering. `1,1` would be the first ordinate of the first vertex.
- JSON: zero-based numbering. `[1][1]` would be the second ordinate of the second vertex.

Two different numbering systems is just asking for trouble.

So I think it would be best to stick with regular SQL where possible. And only use JSON as a last resort.